# Send data back from one activity to another ANDROID KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have this situation.

Let's say I have 3 activities A B & C

From Activity A y open B

I perform certain validations on B and the presents B finishing B using finish()

In C I get the values needed to get back to activity A with a result that I need to display on A.

I did this:

On activity A:

```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    if(requestCode == startValidationActivityCode){
        val message = data!!.getStringExtra("message")
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

I do nothing on activity B

Then in activity C I have the following, where $scannedQTY is the value I need on Activity A:

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
    sendDataToPreviousActivity()
    super.onBackPressed()
}

private fun sendDataToPreviousActivity(){
    val intent = Intent().apply {
        putExtra("message", "This is the qty $scannedQTY")
    }
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
}
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity
```

Any help will be really appreciate it.

Thank you folks!!!

Comment: Hello, try to remove `super.onBackPressed()` from `onBackPressed()`

Comment: If I remove the super.onBackPressed() the back button gets disabled

Comment: please add `finish()` as last line of `sendDataToPreviousActivity` and keep removing `super.onBackPressed()`

Comment: that throws the same error as before. java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity

Comment: Are you opening Activity C with `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`? Is C started by A or B?

Comment: Don't finish activity B until you get your result from C, once you get the required data in B from C, finish with sending the result to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open activities like this: A -> B -> C, and want to retrieve result in activity A from activity C you need to do next steps:

1. Use some common `REQUEST_CODE` variable, e.g. `const val REQUEST_CODE: Int = 400`
2. In activity A start activity B using method `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)`;
3. In activity A override `onActivityResult()` method:

   ```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

       if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
           val message = data!!.getStringExtra("message")
           Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       } else {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       }
   }
   ```
4. In activity B start activity C using method `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)`;
5. In activity B override `onActivityResult()` method:

   ```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

       if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
           makeValidations()

           // pass data back to activity A
           setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
           finish()
       } else {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       }
   }
   ```
6. In activity C to pass data back to activity B:

   ```
   val intent = Intent().apply {
       putExtra("message", "This is the qty $scannedQTY")
   }
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
   finish()
   ```